# CSS class priorities

Tags: css, list, class, css-specificity

I have a question about the priority of CSS classes after encountering a problem today. The situation is as follows:

I have an unordered list which has a class associated with it. The `LI` tags have some styles defined too. I want to change the styling of the `LI`s after a click (via an added `"selected"` class), but the added class's styles are never applied. Is this normal behavior or should this code work?

CSS:

```css
.dynamicList
{
    list-style: none;
}

.dynamicList li
{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.selectedItem
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul class="dynamicList">
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li class="selectedItem">Second (Selected) Item</li>
</ul>
```

The background color of the `"selected"` list item isn't changed. This is also the case if I don't apply the style to the `LI` element, but create another class and apply that to all the list items so it reads..

```html
<li class="listitem selectedItem">xxxx</li>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This sounds like a [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) problem. Try changing your `.selectedItem` ruleset to:

```
.dynamicList li.selectedItem {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Ah of course, what an idiot! thanks a lot for all the really quick answers! Cheers
Stuart

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is that your .selectedItem style isn't getting applied because the previous style is more specific and thus has a higher priority. Here is a [decent rundown](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css):

> Now, let’s make a general list of the
>   internal priorities for CSS (3 has the
>   highest priority):
>
> ```
> element
> .class
> #id
> ```
>
> This is the default priority order. In
>   addition to this, specificity will
>   also count, f.ex ul li will override
>   li. W3C has made a decent table over
>   how you should calculate internal
>   weight:
>
> ```
> LI            {...}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI         {...}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL LI      {...}  /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> LI.red        {...}  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red  {...}  /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> #list         {...}  /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> ```

And here is the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 7):

Change the `selectedItem` rule to:

```
.dynamicList li.selectedItem
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A small addition that was not mentioned by cletus' post.
According to the `W3C` link, the highest priority is the `style` attribute used in the html element/tag.

E.g. if you have

```
<a id= bar style="color: red">foo</a>
```

and

```
<style>
#bar {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

The color will be `red` because the inline html style has the highest priority, higher than `#`.

Comment: I was made aware today that W3C is considered a bad source of information for code: http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: W3C is not a bad source, W3Schools is

Comment: I feel like a pupil so I like W3School, which gives you a lot of info on different topics with examples .. W3C is the oficial standard and an international community so it has to be good by definition, well..