# How to change the label's color of a submenu in a menubar?

Tags: java, netbeans, primefaces

I would like to change the label's color of a submenu, using the menubar.
The code I am using is the following :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form>

                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="font: 12px sans-serif;width:800px;height: 19px">
                    <p:menubar autoDisplay="false" style="padding: 0px">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Tableau de bord" action="#{liens.lienTableauDeBord()}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-home" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;color: white;background-color:#333367"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;color: white;background-color:#333367"/>
                        <p:submenu label="Affaires" style="margin-top: -4px; height: 22px;color: white;background-color:#333367"> 
                            <p:menuitem value="Création" action="#{liens.lienCreerAffaire()}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document"/>  
                            <p:menuitem value="Consultation" action="#{liens.lienConsultationAffaire()}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-search"/>  
                        </p:submenu>  
                        <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="padding: 0px"/>
                        <p:submenu label="Outillages" style="margin-top: -4px;height: 19px"> 
                            <p:menuitem value="Création" action="#{liens.lienNumOutil()}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document" style="padding: 0px"/>  
                            <p:menuitem value="Consultation" url="#" icon="ui-icon-search" style="padding: 0px"/>  
                        </p:submenu> 
                        <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="padding: 0px"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Recherche et consultation DT" url="#" icon="ui-icon-search" style="padding: 0px"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="padding: 0px"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Paramètres" url="#" icon="ui-icon-wrench"  style="padding: 0px"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="padding: 0px"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Déconnexion" url="#" icon="ui-icon-closethick" style="padding: 0px" /> 
                    </p:menubar>  
                </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>



</ui:composition>
```

I am using a PrimeFaces' theme which has white font on every menus, a CSS stylesheet which sets every text's color on white but the labels *Affaires* and *Outillages* won't change to white.
I also tried to change it with the attributes. It works for the *menuitems* but not for the *submenus*.

The text color MUST be white, and the background darkblue (as defined on the CSS stylesheet), but I don't have to use PrimeFaces at all costs.

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 and PrimeFaces 3.4.2

If someone can help me, I'll reward him with a cookie

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is

```
.ui-widget-content a
```

a css rule written in primefaces is  overriding your inline styles

Read more about css rule priority [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), reference SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120174/css-class-priorities)

Add a style class attribute to your sub menu.

e.g:

```
<p:submenu styleClass="affaires" label="Affaires" style="margin-top: -4px; height: 22px;color: white;background-color:#333367"> 
   <p:menuitem value="Création" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document"/>  
   <p:menuitem value="Consultation" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-search"/>  
</p:submenu>
```

And add the css to your page

```
<style>
    .affaires .ui-menuitem-text{color:white;}
</style>
```

Also you can use the below css for setting submenu(popup) background,

```
.affaires .ui-menu-child{background: blue;}
```

Also i suggest you to use firebug(firefox plugin) to inspect css, this solves the problem in most case.

Hope this helps.