# Static bar with text

Tags: css, progress-bar

I would like to make a bar (see image). I have 3 values ​​when I would like to display with text.
I'm using HTML and CSS Is it possible to do it?

[image]

Comment: Try to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567851/how-to-change-the-labels-color-of-a-submenu-in-a-menubar)

Comment: Or see https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/steps.xhtml, but at least clarify how you would like to use this

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to PrimeFaces, so here's a solution using plain HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

```js
let value1 = document.getElementById("value1");
if (value1) { value1.style.width = 150 + "px" }

let value2 = document.getElementById("value2");
if (value2) { value2.style.width = 150 + "px" }

let maxi = document.getElementById("maxi");
if (maxi) { maxi.style.width = 150 + "px" }
```

```css
.bar div { float:left; color:white; padding:1ex; margin:0;
           text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif; }
#value1  { background-color:#5b9bd5; }
#value2  { background-color:#70ad47; }
#maxi    { background-color:#a6a6a6; }
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div id="value1">value1</div>
  <div id="value2">value2</div>
  <div id="maxi">maxi</div>
</div>
```

The JS may need to go inside a function that you call after items have loaded, 
e.g. `<body onload='populate_widths()'>`.

This finds each placeholder and assigns its width programmatically. It assumes each width is 150, which you can change with server-side data or else within the Javascript code.

---

The above snippet demonstrates how you can alter values using Javascript, but if you have static server-side values, you could just pass CGI variables to add the width right into the elements' `style` attributes. I don't know PrimeFaces or other Java-based server side code, but the resulting HTML would look like this:

```css
.bar div { float:left; color:white; padding:1ex; margin:0;
           text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div style="width:150px; background-color:#5b9bd5">value1</div>
  <div style="width:150px; background-color:#70ad47">value2</div>
  <div style="width:150px; background-color:#a6a6a6">maxi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje – The `if` lines are a safeguard against loading too early (in which case the values will be `null`). They're probably unnecessary but I was being thorough. The `populate_widths()` function allows running the JS code after the elements are populated so they'll actually exist. This SO snippet doesn't need it, but the real world may. I interpreted this question as "how do I plot three values as widths like this image?" but the question could have been posed more clearly.