# AngularJS Tabular Navigation Selected Styling

Tags: css, angularjs

I am creating a navigation structure.  I tried to use [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##tabs) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), but as soon as I injected them into my app, Angular failed.  I found this [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/ss/css-3-tabs.htm) and constructed my navigation tab-bar.  I like how easy it is to customize.  My problem is, I don't know how to apply the css for the selected tab in angular.  I can't apply an id to an element conditionally, and when I try and break up the css into multiple classes, the tabs don't display the same way.

```
<ul class="tablist">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabList" ng-click="setSelected($index);">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

vs.

<ul class="tablist">
    <li id="selectedTab"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to apply the selected formatting?  See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qdDD/1/) for a more fleshed out example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120174/css-class-priorities) SO Post that I was able to use and fix the CSS formatting with regards to their priority.

```
.tablist li.selectedTab a {
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #6B74C6;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    color: #0378D9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<ul class="tablist">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabList" ng-click="setSelected($index);" ng-class="{ selectedTab: $index === selected}">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah! thats a better solution instead of important.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/dLemh/6/

to have background color change use css important on the class

```
 ng-class="{selected: isSelected(tab)}"

 $scope.currentSelectedTab = {};
    $scope.setSelectedTab = function(tab){
        $scope.currentSelectedTab = tab
    }

    $scope.isSelected = function(tab){
        if(tab == $scope.currentSelectedTab){
        return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Please let me know if anything

Comment: So I can put the border around it, but I can't make the selected tab go from white text on blue background to blue text on grey background?

Comment: You can do it, I updated to have the css property to .selected a { } and use important.Please check and let me know if anything

Comment: +1 for a working solution.  I also came up with a solution you might want to look at.  I have heard recommendations not to use `!important` except to test CSS for priority.