# How can I override bootstrap classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to override bootstrap default styles on a particular element ,but instead of using important property ,is there any way to do that , sometimes the !important property don't work , i was creating bootstrap form but when i tried to give width to any form control then it didn't apply why ?

Comment: Your question is too broad, can you provide a fiddle and demonstrate clearly what you can't perform ?

Comment: you can use default boostrap classes, they are responsive, they will adjust accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should work with the CSS priorities.

There is a similar topic where you can find helpful info about it **Here:**  [best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css#27704409)

Additionally,  in the following link there is a sample about specificity were you should try in your code to target the elements you need to change **Here:** [CSS class priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120174/css-class-priorities)

If possible share some samples of your code where you have issues.